# ERROR 1070 Apache Pig, using built-in UDF

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions, udf

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252397/apache-pig-script-error-1070-java-udf-could-not-resolve-import), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637391/pig-udf-in-java-error-1070), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346191/pig-error-1070-when-doing-udf), did not solve my problem. They all are making their own UDFs. I want to use a built-in UDF. *Any* built-in UDF. I get the same or similar error for every UDF I have tried.

```
 FOO = LOAD 'filepath/data.csv' 
 USING PigStorage(',') 
 AS (name:string, age:int, kilograms:double);

 BAR = FOREACH FOO GENERATE $0, $1, $2, kilograms*2.2 AS pounds;
```

This works as expected, basically creating the same relation as FOO but with an extra column that has KG converted to LBS.

But if I want to use something like get the log scale of kilograms, like this:

```
 BAR2 = FOREACH FOO GENERATE $0, $1, $2, log(kilograms) AS logscaleKG;
```

I get the following error (or similar):

```
 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve log using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

No UDF seems to work inside a FOREACH GENERATE.

Comment: How did you install Pig? It seems your PATH is not setup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig is a bit finicky about capitalization, you need to capitalize `log`. For example, I can run this code just fine on a fresh Hortonworks Sandbox.

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/kg.csv
one,1
two,2
three,3
```

+

```
grunt> a = LOAD '/tmp/kg.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (txt:chararray, val:int);
grunt> b = FOREACH a GENERATE txt, val, LOG(val);
grunt> DUMP b;
... # Running some MapReduces
(one,1,0.0)
(two,2,0.6931471805599453)
(three,3,1.0986122886681098)
```

Comment: Hmm. Given this and the other comment, it may be my setup. I'll see what a fresh sandbox does for me.

Comment: @wugology - Actually, your problem is that `log` should be all caps - [ReadTheDocs](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#log)

Comment: Cool! Accept my answer?